# drag and drop order of table columns is not maintained when columns are hide/show using *ngIf in ngx-datatable angular 4

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

What we are trying to implement that we want to maintain the drag and drop order of columns when we refresh the page.
After drag and drop we are storing the current column order in localStorage. The next time when page refreshes, we are fetching that column order and passing this to ngx-datatable. - This works fine

We are also using *ngIf to show/hide columns in the table. - This causes the issue(perhaps, i'm not sure).

Below is the scenerio in which we are facing issue:

1. Drag and drop the columns
2. Show/hide a column

After step 2, the order that we got in step 1 is not maintained in the table, below is the gif.

[GIF link showing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7OMh.gif)

```
<ngx-datatable class="" [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="70" [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="30" [scrollbarV]="true (activate)="onActivate($event)" (select)="onSelect($event,row)" [scrollbarH]="true" [selectionType]="'single'" [rows]="rows">

<span *ngFor=" let col of dynamicCol;let i = index">
    <ngx-datatable-column *ngIf="check_show_hide(i,col) " name="{{col}}" prop="{{col}}" [headerClass]="getIsShowColName" class="draggable">
        <ng-template *ngIf="customFilterData[i]" let-sort="sortFn" let-column="column" height="200"  ngx-datatable-header-template>

            <label  class="draggable" draggable="true"  (click)="sort()" style="height:10px;cursor:pointer">{{customFilterData[i].name}}</label>
            <br>
            <input type='text' style='width:100%;height:30px;' placeholder='Filter..' (keyup)='updateFilterNew(customFilterData[i])'
             [(ngModel)]="customFilterData[i].value" [hidden]="customFilterData[i].name === 'Serial_No'"/>
        </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
</span> </ngx-datatable>
```

In above code dynamicCol contains the columns in below format:

```
dynamicCol = ['FirstName', 'MiddleInitial', ...]
```

We are using `headerClass='getIsShowColName'` to get the current order of columns and storing it in `localStorage`.

**Note:** `*ngIf="customFilterData[i]"` is being used to avoid error in console as we are using - `customFilterData[i].name` and `customFilterData[i].value`

We need a solution to maintain the order of columns after hide/show functionality .
Thanks in advance